# when i run the code there is no error on console but my project is not working and there is error on web console

Tags: typescript

external "url":1 Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
    at Object.url (external "url":1)
    at **webpack_require** (bootstrap:83)
    at Object. (client:6)
    at Object../node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client/index.js?http://0.0.0.0:0 (vendor.js:219506)
    at **webpack_require** (bootstrap:83)
    at Object.0 (main.ts:25)
    at **webpack_require** (bootstrap:83)
    at checkDeferredModules (bootstrap:45)
    at Array.webpackJsonpCallback [as push] (bootstrap:32)
    at main.js:1

the project is on angular and electron and there is no webpack files i already searched this error do me some help

i tried all the things to reinstall project again download node modules all the things i already tried but still the same error

Comment: external "url":1 Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
    at Object.url (external "url":1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:83)
    at Object.<anonymous> (client:6)
    at Object../node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client/index.js?http://0.0.0.0:0 (vendor.js:219506)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:83)
    at Object.0 (main.ts:25)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:83)
    at checkDeferredModules (bootstrap:45)
    at Array.webpackJsonpCallback [as push] (bootstrap:32)
    at main.js:1

Answer (score 0):

no body replies....

any how it will work

by writing this simple command on console

npm run ng:serve:web